# Allow pointer events to pass through a nested div

Tags: css

Assuming I have a container, if I have the css:

```
#nested2 {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

It does not work unless I make `wrapper` have the `pointer-events: none`. The issue is I want to have only nested2 have events pass through it and not nested1.

What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `pointer-events:none` for the whole `#wrapper`, then override that style in `#nested1` with `pointer-events:auto`:

```
#wrapper {
  pointer-events:none;
}
#nested1 {
  pointer-events:auto;
}
```

Of course the tradeoff here is the `#wrapper` won't be able to receive mouse events. However I hope you interest in the nested divs inside.